# Why do I keep destroying my text files?

Tags: shell, text-processing, io-redirection

I have destroyed a bunch of non-essential files and I don't know why. I have been executing commands like:

```
tr -sc 'A-Za-z' '\n' > somefile.txt | less
```

there is no output (blank page with flashing END) and upon checking all the content from the file is erased.

Another command that erased a full text file

```
grep someword > someotherfile.txt  | less
```

Comment: You may want to read [what is meant by connecting STDOUT and STDIN?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/31339#31339)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `>` operator means "take the output of the command, truncate the named file, and then write the output of the command to that.

Reading that command line I guess you want `<`, which is "read standard input from this file, and feed it to the command" instead.

Comment: this has to be the stupidest question on the site. thanks.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with not knowing things.  Everyone starts out from zero.

Comment: “There is no shame in not knowing; the shame lies in not finding out.” -- Russian Proverb

Comment: Ooooh.  I've never had the redirect operators explained in that way, comparatively.  I've been a casual linux user for years (not full time, obviously), and never learned properly how to use the < operator.  Now I know, and this answer is what did it.  @kuchnahi, even the veterans and long-time users are learning new things, every day.  Don't sweat it.  :)

Comment: Still, surely it would make some sense to _read the documentation_ for the language features you use, no?

Answer (score 12):

While you make yourself familiar with I/O redirection, you might find it "safer" to enable `noclobber` shell setting. This prevents unintentional clobbering of your files. See your shell man page and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clobbering

Comment: +1 great tip, and this is something I do, even with many years of experience. Typos happen, and this helps.

Comment: I still have to think twice with < and >.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 6):

These commands have clobbered the text file because you told it to (`> file` will truncate any existing file before writing to it). You are probably looking for `<`, which means "redirect standard input *from* here".