# less command with pipe

Tags: shell, pipe, command

I learn that pipe (`|`) is used to pass stdout into subshell's stdin.

But, command `less` must have filename argument like `less file1.txt`

However, when I use command like `ls -l /root | less`, it works.

So, I assumed that in this case, less takes `stdin` *file* which is written from `ls -l /root`'s stdout. I mean, in real, `less stdin` when less do its own command. But, because of another command, I got confused. It's `tr` command.

`tr` command doesn't take any *file* argument like `tr a-z A-Z file1.txt`. It just take stdin from keyboard or redirected stdin. But, command `ls -l /root | tr a-z A-Z` is possible. Then, what I assumed is wrong.

How pipe works in real? The basic is that pipe passes main shell's standard output into subshell's standard input. But, I can't know main shell's standard output goes to subshell's standard input *file* or just it takes situation that I enter the characters from keyboard. But, when I see above examples, shell takes both situations.

Comment: `less` will accept a filename, but if no file is given, it reads from `stdin`.  That is specific to the `less` command so not relevant to `tr`.  Pipes in general are implemented as a special type of file called "FIFO" (first in first out) which is temporarily created by the shell to allow one command to read what another command outputs.  In a simple two command pipeline, the `stdout` of the first command is directed to the FIFO (write-only), and the `stdin` of the second command is directed *from* the FIFO (read only).  But you can pretend the first command writes directly to the second.

Comment: But, when I use `less` without file argument(for example, just `less`), it doesn't take `stdin` from keyboard. Is it just internal mechanism from less?

Comment: See my updated reply.

Comment: Yes, `less(1)` takes *commands* from the keyboard, taking input from there simultaneously makes no sense. Other programs that don't take commands just don't care to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, I assumed that in this case, `less` takes `stdin` *file* which is written from `ls -l /root`'s stdout.

This is correct, and it doesn't contradict what you observed with `tr`.

The shell's [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) construct (`PRODUCER | CONSUMER`) creates an [anonymous pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_pipe) before starting the two processes `PRODUCER` and `CONSUMER`. An anonymous pipe is a type of file that doesn't have a name, it doesn't have a directory entry, but it can be read and written normally. In a pipeline, the shell connects the write end of the pipe to the producer's stdout and the read end of the pipe to the consumer's stdin.

The `tr` command only ever reads data from stdin and writes to stdout. The `less` command does this only if you don't pass it a file name on the command line; if you pass a file name to `less`, it reads from this file instead of reading from stdin. What `less` does is a common convention, followed by many similar applications that read data from one file.

You may also be interested in [what is meant by connecting STDOUT and STDIN?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/what-is-meant-by-connecting-stdout-and-stdin/31339#31339) and [How can a command have more than one output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96724/how-can-a-command-have-more-than-one-output/96807#96807)

Answer (score 4):

> I learn that pipe (|) is used to pass stdout into subshell's stdin.

It passes the left command stdout to the right command stdin. Whether one or both of these commands run in a subshell is shell implementation specific.

In any case, the shell doesn't care about arguments being passed or not to either commands. It is up to the programs to do what they want with their stdin and stdout, including ignoring them.

Note too that programs are able to detect if their stdin is a `tty`, i.e. interactive keyboard, or not and act accordingly. This is what you observe with the `less` command which, when given no arguments, normally reads its standard input but refuses to process it if it is a `tty`, as its [source code](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/download.html) shows :

```
  if (isatty(fd0))
  {
    error("Missing filename (\"less --help\" for help)", NULL_PARG);
    quit(QUIT_OK);
  }
```