# Can I simulate the tee util using extra file descriptors?

Tags: shell, io-redirection

I haven't quite wrapped my head around how to use additional file descriptors. I suspect you could use them to simulate what the `tee` utility does, viewing a command's output while simultaneously writing it to a file. I also suspect doing so would help me better understand how to use additional file descriptors...

My attempts so far,

```
date 3>&1 3>file
```

My thinking was, create **3** as a duplicate of **1** (stdout) and redirect **3** to write to `file`, thus I have stdout writing to the terminal as usual, and **3** writing to a file.

But this doesn't work. When I `cat file`, it's empty. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A redirection operator *changes* where output is going (or where input is coming from). `3>&1` means “make file descriptor 3 point wherever file descriptor 1 is currently pointing” (which is the terminal). `3>file` means “make file descriptor 3 point to `file`”. Nothing happened during the brief time fd 3 was pointing to the terminal, so you don't get any terminal output.

In order to obtain the same data in two locations, something needs to copy the data. This is the job of `tee`. For every byte that it reads, it outputs that byte twice (if given one file argument, plus its standard output).

Don't get bogged down by the fact that `>&` is sometimes called duplication. What it's duplicating is the *file descriptor*: `3>&1` duplicates fd 1 to fd 3, meaning that the data going to fd 1 and the data going to fd 3 are getting merged — they're both going to wherever fd 1 was pointing.

If you prefer graphical explanations, see [what is meant by connecting STDOUT and STDIN?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/what-is-meant-by-connecting-stdout-and-stdin/31339#31339) and [How can a command have more than one output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96724/how-can-a-command-have-more-than-one-output/96807#96807)

In any case, your command doesn't output anything on file descriptor 3, so redirecting fd 3 doesn't change anything. The `date` command writes to its standard output, i.e. fd 1, and you aren't redirecting that.

---

Zsh has a feature called [multios](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios) that changes the meaning of output redirection. If there are multiple output redirections for the same command on the same file descriptor, then the first one *changes* where that descriptor is pointing, but subsequent ones *replicate* the data to the specified targets. For example, to get output in a file in addition to wherever stdout was pointing, you can use

```
date >&1 >file
```

Zsh is doing the job of `tee`. Note that the order of redirections matter — `date >file >&1` would write to `file` twice, since by the time the `>&1` operator is evaluated the standard output of `date` is already going to `file`.

Answer (score 1):

No, because it doesn't duplicate the output. To duplicate the file descriptors, you also have to output to them twice.

Although you can do it with a loop, like so:

```
while read l
do
   echo "$l" >&3
   echo "$l" >&4
done
```

With binary data it will be buggy (zeros chunked out, crlf-s will be converted to lf).

Your example did this:

1. opened fd 3 to file
2. cloned fd 1 to *in the place of fd 3* (i.e. it *closed* your previous fd3 and then make fd3 to be an "alternative address" of your previous stdout).

The redirection is essentally a clone, in unix terminology, it is like a hard link. With a `3>&1` suffix to a commant, you will have fd 3 and fd 1 pointing to the same entity (which is now `file`).

If you have some affinity to C, I would like to check a `man 3 dup2`, this is exactly what an fd redirection does.