# How does the tee command works?

Tags: tee

After coming across about 3 `tee` explanations I regard as undidactic, I would ask for a simple, general, and stepped (if possible) explanation about this command, aimed for Linux newcomers.

I do understand we use it either through a pipe, on a command's stdout, or alternatively, directly a certain file, but I think I miss what the command actually do with this content and when it is useful.

So here's what I ask, hoping to find a didactic explanation, served to newcomers in a clear, stepped way:

1. How does the command work with either with a command's stdout, or alternatively, the files themselves?
2. Why is it common to say `tee` reads standard input? I mean, if I do `ls -l`, `tee` doesn't read the syntax `ls -l` itself but rather the stdout it printed into the session.

Also, if you want, please share a practical example from your daily work as to when `tee` is very useful to you?

Comment: There's no such thing as "stdout of a file". _Processes_ have standard input and standard output.

Comment: What I meant by that is that when you do cat/less/tail, you get a stdout of the file you choose to display. I really desire to have your opinion on why it isn't semantic and we can't say "this stdout is of file XYZ"?

Comment: “a stdout of the file” is not common terminology, and it is not a good way to describe what happens. To understand this, you must first unlearn what makes you describe it that way.

Comment: The "standard output of `cat file`" will _contain_ the contents of the file `file`, but it's still the standard output of `cat`, not _of_ the file.

Comment: @Benia, Processes communicate through file descriptors, that can point to files, network sockets, pipes to other processes, or whatever. On the userspace-kernel border, fd's are identified by numbers, and by standards and custom, fd's 0,1,2 have a well-understood meaning, namely being the "standard" input, output and error output. As an analogy, imagine the process as a machine, and fd's as tubes coming out of the machine. That works with the pipeline analogy, we have interchangeable machines with tubes labeled "stdin" and "stdout", and a pipeline just connects them together, stdout to stdin.

Comment: @Benia, what the process does with the stuff flowing in from the tubes, is up to it. `cat` just copies stuff as-is, `wc -l` counts the lines in the input and prints that into its output, `ls` takes no input from stdin, but asks the OS for a file listing, and then prints that to its standard output.

Comment: Gilles and kusalananda, I now understand why the term "stdout of a certain file" is uncommon in regards to stdout of a command (that deals with a certain file). Thus I've unlearned that it is best to use this phrase and from now usually say "stdout of a command" (whether piped to be processed with one or more extra commands or not).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the `tee` manual on my system:

> The tee utility copies standard input to standard output, making a copy
>        in zero or more files.  The output is unbuffered.

So, it reads from standard input and copies it to standard output, and while doing so also duplicates the stream into one or several files.

In the following pipeline, `tee` would take the output of the first command in the pipeline and copy it to standard output (the terminal) while also making copies of it in the files `one`, `two` and `three`:

```
$ somecommand | tee one two three
```

`tee` has many uses, one is in conjunction with `sudo` to redirect output to a file owned by root:

```
$ somecommand | sudo tee /root/somefile >/dev/null
```

The following would *not* have worked since the redirection happens as the unprivileged user (it would also run `somecommand` as root which may be unwanted):

```
$ sudo somecommand >/root/somefile
```

An artificial example of appending a fixed set of lines to many files at once (to all users `~/.profile` files, assuming that the `*` expands to the usernames and that the expanded command line does not become too long for the shell to handle):

```
$ tee -a /home/*/.profile <<'END_NEWPATH'
PATH="$PATH:/opt/bin"
END_NEWPATH
```

A real example of using `tee`:

```
time doas box-build.sh 2>&1 | tee build.out |  grep '^=*>'
```

This is me building the OpenBSD base system. `doas` is [the OpenBSD "equivalent" of `sudo`](http://man.openbsd.org/doas) and `box-build.sh` is a small shell script that does the building (essentially `cd /usr/src && make obj && make build`). I'd like to store the output of the whole build process, including any errors or warnings, but I don't want to have everything spewing out into my terminal.  To this end I use `tee` to save everything into `build.out` and then `grep` to only get a hint of where in the process we are in the terminal.

See also the other questions here that are tagged with the [tee](/questions/tagged/tee) tag.

Comment: Hi Kusalananda. I am sorry to say I didn't understand the first part of the answer hence didn't feel comfortable to keep reading (so I won't make wrong assumptions because of my possibly wrong understanding of the first part) --- You say `it reads from standard input and copies it to standard output`. What does that mean? If I type `ls -l` it doesn't work with the `ls- l`, rather, with data associated with it which I can call "stdout" given after executing `ls -l` so to me it seems tee works with the stdout, not the stdin which is `ls -l`.

Comment: @Benia Your difficulty seems to be related to file descriptors and pipes, not to the `tee` command. See [what is meant by connecting STDOUT and STDIN?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/what-is-meant-by-connecting-stdout-and-stdin/31339#31339)

Comment: @Benia `ls -l` writes a directory listing to _its_ standard output. If you pipe that stream to `tee`, it becomes `tee`'s standard input. The standard output of one process is the standard input of the next process in the pipeline. If you say `cat file`, the standard output of that will contain the contents of the file, but it is the standard output of the `cat` process.